# Sqlite Remote Manangment and multiple record

Tags: c#, web-services, sqlite, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

first hi all,

i got a db sqlite in my project also got xml files and i translate data from xml and save to local db,

```
 string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
  string localFilename = "personel.xml";
  string localPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
```

this is my local db, im planing to move db3 to iss, when i move should i give

```
 localpath like = 192.23.21.2/www/personel.xml?
```

or should i add more things like http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/ ?

and second question

what if multiple users update or delete from table?

there is a one db3 file and same time 3 connections how can i manage it?

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) is not designed to work as a multi-user database.

> If you have many client programs accessing a common database over a
>   network, you should consider using a client/server database engine
>   instead of SQLite.

It is also a really bad idea to allow your mobile client app to talk directly to a remote database.  This is why web services are usually recommended as an additional layer between your client and a central, remote database.  They allow you to introduce an additional layer of control and security over your data access.

Comment: that was really great answer thanks Jason, but i dont have much db knowledge i can mod, up and insert at device but is there sample of web services? a scenerio; files.db3 live active at server, send commands to remote db? wcf? or send commands with message? i really confsed sorry

Comment: The Xamarin article you linked to has a simple WCF example.  Webservices are a standard programming topic these days - there are thousands of examples available.  If you are using .NET on your server search on "WCF".